# Why i am not getting exact location on google map using google map geocoding api

Tags: google-maps, location

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Chopra Eye Hospital, H No-3, Pocket C-8, Sector 7, Near Rohini east Metro Station, Rohini&sensor=false

Comment: Reverse geocoding takes coordinates and returns an address.  It looks like you are geocoding (translating an address into coordinates), but you are providing a place, not a postal address.

Comment: Hi, please mark my answer as accepted if it resolved your query.

Comment: what is wrong in my question and why it is rated as negative ? If I am wrong then you need to give solutions and if question is not understandable then you mark it as negative. @sandeep: your answer is help full but negative remark on question is not understandable.

Comment: users give negative remark if your question is not clear or not according to  StackOverflow rules. Now in case of your question i don't know who downvoted but, your question does not contain relevant info, like in your question body you dint mention anything other than link that also broken. I suggest you write question as if you are narrating to non technical person with all relevant codes and explanation.

Comment: if my answer helped and solved your problem then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bhai, you are Geocoding not Reverse geocoding.

**Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.

**Reverse geocoding** is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address. The Google Maps Geocoding API's reverse geocoding service also lets you find the address for a given place ID.

**Refer:**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

---

In this question you are locating Chopra eye hospital by passing the address in url, but the url shoul not have space character .In google maps space should be replaced by `+`.
So your url should look like

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Chopra+Eye+Hospital,+H+No-3,+Pocket+C-8,+Sector+7,+Near+Rohini+east+Metro+Station,+Rohini&sensor=false

But this will also not work because the address is Postal address .

The url for Geocoding Chopra Hospital, Rohini is:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Chopra+Eye+Hospital,+Pradeep+Bhatia+Marg,+Rohini,+New+Delhi,+Delhi&sensor=false
This will return json data which You should process and use.